# Angular 6 : Scripts not loading correctly from angular.json

Tags: javascript, css, angular6

I have not found yet the solution of this in the internet.

Angular brought this similar [Github Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11044) , but can't find any solution there.

I have added my script files to angular.json such as (in both build & test scope):

```
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "src/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js",
          "src/assets/plugins/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.js",
          "src/assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js",
          "src/assets/plugins/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js",
          "src/assets/plugins/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/jquery.subscribe-better.js",

          "src/assets/js/moment-with-locales.min.js",
          "src/assets/plugins/countdown/jquery.plugin.min.js",
          "src/assets/plugins/countdown/jquery.countdown.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/theme.js"
        ]
```

I am getting the css styles but some scripts are not working correctly.

Any solution?

Comment: Any error message in browser console?

Comment: Nope, it seems everything are working fine from the console.

Comment: "some scripts are not working correctly." ... what do you mean? are the scripts not included in the build?

Comment: @fransyozef scripts are included in the build, but say, my theme.js is working but jquery.countdown.min.js is not working. I have gone through every codes to see which functions are not working, so If I have 10 js, 3 js are working. 7 js are not working... weird though. and for verifying the js files, I have executed without angular and those files are corrects.

Comment: jQuery 1.11.3 ??? In general is a bad idea using angular + jquery, but the jquery actual version is 3.3.1

Comment: @fransyozef , I have found that, for some different routing and lazy modules configurations, The js files are working, but If I configure my routing configuration  according to my needs, it's not working, So I think I have some routing configuration problem, will you look at that ?

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of hours of trial-and-error, I found out that I was putting the script paths under the json key of

`/projects/project-name/architect/test/options/scripts`

instead of (if not both)

`/projects/project-name/architect/build/options/scripts`

P.S.: It may also apply to the "styles.css not working" type of questions.

Comment: This was my issue as well. Worth noting that this is inside `angular.json`